# What is Error code 1 for netsh.exe?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, error-code, netsh

When running the following command I **sometimes** get returning Error code 1 and the certificate is **not** bound in that case.

`C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:20102 certhash=1949E24D0B5F557A7525D739F7229B97ADD344FF appid={0f5be1ce-e2f8-41ab-ab18-d78759c5dc55}`

The command is executed by a Windows Service running as SYSTEM account and usually works.

What means Error code 1 in that case? I can't find any error code reference on Google.